# Does anyone know how to use Delete method in api?

Tags: api, react-native, expo

I am newbie here, want to know how to use DELETE METHOD API in my react native project.
I only know method "GET" and "POST"!

Thanks in advance

Comment: its just like get and post but its "DELETE" just expect no response

Comment: fetch( http://url/users/address/delete/id/token,
         {
             method: 'DELETE',
             headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
             //body: JSON.stringify({user_address_id: id})
         })
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(res => {
             console.log(res)
         })

Comment: thats my code, like that sir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Delete` work same as `GET` and `POST`, see below example and you can easily modify as per your need. Good Luck :)

```
function deleteToken(token) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('token', token);
        return fetch('YOUR_URL', {
            method: 'DELETE',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
    }

    deleteToken(token)
       .then((json) => {
           // handle success
        })
       .catch(error => error);
```

Comment: I shared the way to fire Delete api, if data still exists than you might be passing wrong data or issue is with backend

Comment: just forgot to add "/"..

thank u sir, it solved now :))

Comment: I am glad I helped you :)